# Голосовой ассистент - непонятная ошибка

Tags: python

Пишу голосового ассистента. В python IDLE всё нормально работает,а через консоль, когда дело доходит до выбора команды,закрывается с непонятной ошибкой.

```
import os
import webbrowser
import sys
import pyttsx3
import datetime, time
import random
import pyowm
from requests_html import HTMLSession
speak = pyttsx3.init()
name = os.path.isfile("name.txt")
data = 'дата', 'скажи дату', 'какая дата'
r = random.randint(1, 8)
_time_ = 'скажи время', 'сколько время', 'какое сейчас время'
no = 'нет', 'нет спасибо', 'больше нет'
yes = 'да', 'нужно', 'нет нужно'
vi = 'выход'
ch = 1, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61
gl = 'а', 'о', 'э', 'е', 'и', 'ы', 'у', 'ё', 'ю', 'я', 'е'
sogl =  'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ'
com = "что вы хотели?", "что мне сделать?", "вы что-то хотели?"
weather = 'погода', 'скажи погоду', 'расскажи погоду'
i = 0

if name == True:
    f = open("name.txt", "r")
    name1 = f.read()
    f.close()
    print("привет", name1)
    speak.say("привет" + name1)
    speak.runAndWait()
    dr = datetime.date(2004, 5, 22)
    aa = datetime.date.today()
    if aa.month == dr.month and aa.day == dr.day:
        print("Поздравляю тебя с днем рождения!")
        speak.say("Поздравляю тебя с днем рождения!")
        speak.runAndWait()
        time.sleep(1)
    com1 = random.choice(com)
    print(com1)
    speak.say(com1)
    speak.runAndWait()
    while True:
        mycom = input(":")
        while True:
            if mycom in weather:
                owm = pyowm.OWM('a761341d5c07239dd9ab9f8c69c94aa2', language = 'ru')
                _weather_ = input("город/страна:")
                observation =  owm.weather_at_place(_weather_)
                w =  observation.get_weather()
                weather1 = _weather_[-1]
                if weather1 in sogl:
                    city = _weather_ + 'е'
                    ww = w.get_detailed_status()
                    print('В', city, 'сейчас', ww)
                    speak.say('В' + city + 'сейчас' + ww)
                    speak.runAndWait()
                    temp = w.get_temperature ('celsius')["temp"]
                    if temp in ch:              
                        print('температура в районе',temp, 'градуса')
                        speak.say('температура в районе' + str(temp) + 'градуса')
                        speak.runAndWait()
                        i +=1
                        if i == r:
                            print("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                            speak.say("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                            speak.runAndWait()
                            i -=r
                            while True:
                                comc = input(":")
                                if comc in no:
                                    print('завершение программы...')
                                    time.sleep(2)
                                    sys.exit()
                                    break
                                elif comc in yes:
                                    print('')
                                    break
                                else:
                                    print('я тебя не поняла')
                                    speak.say('я тебя не поняла')
                                    speak.runAndWait()
                        break
                    else:               
                        print('температура в районе',temp, 'градусов')
                        speak.say('температура в районе' + str(temp) + 'градусов')
                        speak.runAndWait()
                        i +=1
                        if i == r:
                            print("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                            speak.say("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                            speak.runAndWait()
                            i -=r
                            while True:
                                comc = input(":")
                                if comc in no:
                                    print('завершение программы...')
                                    time.sleep(2)
                                    sys.exit()
                                    break
                                elif comc in yes:
                                    print('')
                                    break
                                else:
                                    print('я тебя не поняла')
                                    speak.say('я тебя не поняла')
                                    speak.runAndWait()
                        break
                elif weather1 in gl:
                    _weather_ = _weather_[0:-1]
                    city3 = _weather_ + 'е'
                    ww = w.get_detailed_status()
                    print('В', city3, 'сейчас', ww)
                    speak.say('В' + city3 + 'сейчас' + ww)
                    speak.runAndWait()
                    temp = w.get_temperature ('celsius')["temp"]
                    if temp in ch:              
                        print('температура в районе',temp, 'градуса')
                        speak.say('температура в районе' + str(temp) + 'градуса')
                        speak.runAndWait()
                        i +=1
                        if i == r:
                            print("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                            speak.say("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                            speak.runAndWait()
                            i -=r
                            while True:
                                comc = input(":")
                                if comc in no:
                                    print('завершение программы...')
                                    time.sleep(2)
                                    sys.exit()
                                    break
                                elif comc in yes:
                                    print('')
                                    break
                                else:
                                    print('я тебя не поняла')
                                    speak.say('я тебя не поняла')
                                    speak.runAndWait()
                        break
                    else:               
                        print('температура в районе',temp, 'градусов')
                        speak.say('температура в районе' + str(temp) + 'градусов')
                        speak.runAndWait()
                        i +=1
                        if i == r:
                            print("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                            speak.say("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                            speak.runAndWait()
                            i -=r
                            while True:
                                comc = input(":")
                                if comc in no:
                                    print('завершение программы...')
                                    time.sleep(2)
                                    sys.exit()
                                    break
                                elif comc in yes:
                                    print('')
                                    break
                                else:
                                    print('я тебя не поняла')
                                    speak.say('я тебя не поняла')
                                    speak.runAndWait()
                        break
            elif mycom in _time_:
                qe = time.strftime("сейчас %X", time.localtime()) 
                print(qe)
                speak.say(qe)
                speak.runAndWait()
                i +=1
                if i == r:
                    print("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                    speak.say("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                    speak.runAndWait()
                    i -=r
                    while True:
                        comc = input(":")
                        if comc in no:
                            print('завершение программы...')
                            time.sleep(2)
                            sys.exit()
                            break
                        elif comc in yes:
                            print('')
                            break
                        else:
                            print('я тебя не поняла')
                            speak.say('я тебя не поняла')
                            speak.runAndWait()
                break
            elif mycom in data:
                _qe_ = time.strftime("сегодня %B %d, %Y год", time.localtime())
                print(_qe_)
                speak.say(_qe_)
                speak.runAndWait()
                i +=1
                if i == r:
                    print("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                    speak.say("вам еще что-то нужно?")
                    speak.runAndWait()
                    i -=r
                    while True:
                        comc = input(":")
                        if comc in no:
                            print('завершение программы...')
                            time.sleep(2)
                            sys.exit()
                            break
                        elif comc in yes:
                            print('')
                            break
                        else:
                            print('я тебя не поняла')
                            speak.say('я тебя не поняла')
                            speak.runAndWait()
                break

            elif mycom in vi:
                print('завершение программы...')
                time.sleep(2)
                sys.exit()  
            else:
                if 'найди' in mycom:
                    poisk = mycom.replace('найди', '')
                    webrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=10735&text='+ poisk)
                elif 'скажи' in mycom:
                    poisk1 = mycom.replace('скажи', '')
                    webrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=10735&text='+ poisk1)
                else:
                    webrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=10735&text='+ mycom)

elif name == False:
    name2 = input("имя:")
    f = open("name.txt", "a")
    f.write(name2)
    f.close()
    print("привет", name2)
    speak.say("привет" + name2)
    speak.runAndWait()
input()`введите сюда код`
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке прикрепите

Comment: а что это у вас за последний input такой интересный?

Comment: чтобы когда в консоли запускаешь,после завершения она не закрылась,это не от этого

Comment: > когда в консоли запускаешь,после завершения она не закрылась

> для этого есть os.system("pause").

Comment: Вы можете прикрепить информацию, сообщение об ошибке, или хотя бы, как её инсценировать, а не "при запуске через консоль закрывается с непонятной ошибкой"?